# Elasticsearch condition on field with dot in key

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a condition on an aggregation eg.

```
  "condition" : {
    "compare" : {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total" : { 
        "gte" : 5 
      }
  }
```

The problem is the `percentile_ranks` aggregations has as it's key a decimal value:

```
{
    "aggregations":{
        "test": {
            "values" :{
                "2200.0" : 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to access the value `100` as there's a dot as part of it's key, `ctx.payload.aggregations.test.values.?`

Comment: What does the actual document look like? Is there literally a field named "2200.0"?

Comment: if you are using javascript something like this should work since the key is a string:
aggregation.test.values["2200.0"]